# How to fix myget.org authorization problem in .NET CORE 3.0.100-preview7-012821?

Tags: asp.net-core, nuget, myget

I'm getting the following error when run `dotnet watch run` in my .NET core 3.0 project folder. I'm not getting error when I build the project inside the `Visual Studio 2019` IDE.

I have `Visual Studio 2019` and `.NET core 3.0 preview` installed.

```
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\3.0.100-preview7-012821\NuGet.targets(123,5): error : Unable to load the service index for source https://www.myget.org/F/mycompany/api/v3/index.json. [C:\myproject\myproject.csproj]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\3.0.100-preview7-012821\NuGet.targets(123,5): error : Response status code does not indicate success: 401 (Unauthorized). [C:\myproject\myproject.csproj]
```